# How to calculate pi to N number of places in C# using loops

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math, loops

How might I go about calculating PI in C# to a certain number of decimal places?

I want to be able to pass a number into a method and get back PI calculated to that number of decimal places.

```
public decimal CalculatePi(int places)
{
    // magic
    return pi;
}

Console.WriteLine(CalculatePi(5)); // Would print 3.14159

Console.WriteLine(CalculatePi(10)); // Would print 3.1415926535
```

etc...

I don't care about the speed of the program. I just want it to be as simple and easy to understand as it can be.

Comment: Simple to understand in terms of programming, or in terms of math?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Development_of_efficient_formulae

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/pi There are sample methods that calculate pi to 20 places, however some limitations are discussed such as lack of precision

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much searching I found this little snippet:

```
public static class BigMath
{
    // digits = number of digits to calculate;
    // iterations = accuracy (higher the number the more accurate it will be and the longer it will take.)
    public static BigInteger GetPi(int digits, int iterations)
    {
        return 16 * ArcTan1OverX(5, digits).ElementAt(iterations)
            - 4 * ArcTan1OverX(239, digits).ElementAt(iterations);
    }

    //arctan(x) = x - x^3/3 + x^5/5 - x^7/7 + x^9/9 - ...
    public static IEnumerable<BigInteger> ArcTan1OverX(int x, int digits)
    {
        var mag = BigInteger.Pow(10, digits);
        var sum = BigInteger.Zero;
        bool sign = true;
        for (int i = 1; true; i += 2)
        {
            var cur = mag / (BigInteger.Pow(x, i) * i);
            if (sign)
            {
                sum += cur;
            }
            else
            {
                sum -= cur;
            }
            yield return sum;
            sign = !sign;
        }
    }
}
```

It is working like a charm so far. You just have to add the System.Numerics library from the GAC to resolve the BigInteger type.

Comment: This will be faster if you don't use `IEnumerable` and `ElementAt`, but just provide `ArcTan1OverX` the number of iterations to make.

Comment: @Dani, how much faster?

Comment: @Dani Create a new answer with your optimizations applied to Chev's snippet.

Answer (score 19):

First, assuming you want some arbitrary number of digits of pi, and we do not want to be confined with the precision of any of the various floating point numbers out there, let us define a Pi function as a string rather than any number type.

One of the coolest algorithms I found while searching for this technique is the [Stanley Rabinowitz and Stan Wagon - Spigot Algorithm](http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/spigot.pdf). It requires no floating point math, and is mostly an iterative method. It does require some memory for storing integer arrays in the intermediate calculations.

Without taking the time to streamline or clean the code here is an implementation of the algorithm (note the result does not add the decimal point).

Please be sure to cite the algorithm and this site if you intend to use this code for anything other than personal use.

### C# Code

```
public static string CalculatePi(int digits)
{   
    digits++;

    uint[] x = new uint[digits*10/3+2];
    uint[] r = new uint[digits*10/3+2];
    
    uint[] pi = new uint[digits];

    for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
        x[j] = 20;
        
    for (int i = 0; i < digits; i++)
    {
        uint carry = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
        {
            uint num = (uint)(x.Length - j - 1);
            uint dem = num * 2 + 1;

            x[j] += carry;

            uint q = x[j] / dem;
            r[j] = x[j] % dem;

            carry = q * num;
        }
        
        
        pi[i] = (x[x.Length-1] / 10);
            
                    
        r[x.Length - 1] = x[x.Length - 1] % 10; ;
        
        for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
            x[j] = r[j] * 10;
    }
    
    var result = "";
    
    uint c = 0;
    
    for(int i = pi.Length - 1; i >=0; i--)
    {
        pi[i] += c;
        c = pi[i] / 10;
        
        result = (pi[i] % 10).ToString() + result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

### Update

I finally got around to fixing the "carry error" that happens after 35 digits. Page 6 of the linked document, in fact, specifically talks about what is going on here. I have tested the final version good to 1000 digits.

Comment: @Levitikon, I have not looked at this for a while, and I kind of quit working on it after a different answer was accepted. I'll review it sometime this week to see if I can't find where it goes wrong.

Comment: @fubo - after 4 years, you have finally motivated me to fix it

Comment: @Levitikon, about 3 years ago you asked if there were any updates on it... i have finally fixed it

Comment: great, I've testet it with 100k digits - seems to work +1

Comment: PDF File is archived here: http://web.archive.org/web/20110714045240/http://www.mathpropress.com/stan/bibliography/spigot.pdf

Answer (score 7):

```
Math.Round(Math.PI, places)
```

If you need more precision you will have trouble using the double data type as it supports a certain max. precision (which is provided by Math.PI).

Comment: Yes, you did answer the question, but no this was not what the question asker wanted ;-).

Comment: This only lets me go to 15 places.

Comment: Decimal always has 4 decimal places? Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @AlexFord: Then you need to define the domain of your problem better. This method works for the two examples you give (5 and 10 d.p.) What is you maximum number of decimal places?

Comment: @MattBurland I'd like it to go pretty high. Let's say 1000 places just for kicks.

Comment: @MattBurland, I clarified: "after the decimal point". Decimal is basically made for money.

Comment: @usr: Yes, I know what decimal is for, but your comment is still nonsense. If I do this: `decimal myPi = (decimal)Math.Round(Math.PI, 10);` I get 3.1415926536. In other words, 10 decimal places in a decimal type. Go ahead and check the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)

Comment: @MattBurland, indeed! Where did I get that from? Thanks for letting me know. I'll have to audit all my code that is using decimals now...

Comment: @usr: Mixed up with some other language / platform?

Answer (score 7):

Same algorithm as nicholas but uses yield for lazy evaluation

```
    static public IEnumerable<uint> Pi()
    {
        uint[] x = new uint[short.MaxValue];
        uint[] r = new uint[short.MaxValue];

        for (int j = 0; j < short.MaxValue; j++)
            x[j] = 20;

        for (int i = 0; i < short.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            uint carry = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
            {
                uint num = (uint)(x.Length - j - 1);
                uint dem = num * 2 + 1;

                x[j] += carry;

                uint q = x[j] / dem;
                r[j] = x[j] % dem;

                carry = q * num;
            }

            yield return (x[x.Length - 1] / 10);

            r[x.Length - 1] = x[x.Length - 1] % 10; ;
            for (int j = 0; j < x.Length; j++)
            {
                x[j] = r[j] * 10;
            }                    
        }
    }
```

I used short.MaxValue as the upper bound for the number of places but that is because my machine is low on virtual memory. A better machine should be able to accommodate up to int.MaxValue.

The function can be called like so:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        foreach (uint digit in Calculator.Pi().Take(100))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(digit);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: Invalid result. It's a 4 instead of a 5 at the 35th digit - look at nicholas ' update

Answer (score 4):

If you are satisfied with the number of digits provided by the native math library, then it is simple; just round to the desired number of digits. If you need more digits (dozens, or hundreds, or thousands), you need a spigot algorithm that spits out the digits one at a time. Jeremy Gibbons gives an [algorithm](http://web.comlab.ox.ac.uk/people/Jeremy.Gibbons/publications/spigot.pdf) which I [implement](http://programmingpraxis.com/2009/02/20/the-digits-of-pi/) [twice](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/06/19/digits-of-e/) at my blog, where you will find code in Scheme, C, Python, Haskell, Perl and Forth (but not C#, sorry).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to store a large number of digits pi in a String constant. Then whenever you need `n` digits of precision, you just take a substring from 0 to `n+2`.