# Calculate the first n digits of pi?

Tags: c#, algorithm, decimal, calculator, pi

Hi i am trying to code Calculate the first n digits of pi

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
namespace PiCalculator
{
    
    class Program
    {
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Decimal.Precision = 5;
            Console.WriteLine("How Many Digit?");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            decimal pi = 0;
            decimal t = 0;
            decimal deno = 0;
            int k = 0;

            t=1*(Factorial(1))*(13591409+545140134*k);
            deno = ((decimal)Factorial(3*k))*((decimal)Math.Pow((double)Factorial(k),3))*((decimal)(Math.Pow(640320,(3*k))));
            pi += t/deno;
            pi = pi * 12 / (decimal)Math.Pow(640320,1.5);
            pi = 1/pi;

            Console.WriteLine(pi);
        }

        // Factorial fonksiyonu
        static decimal Factorial(int n)
        {
            if (n == 0)
                return 1;

            return n * Factorial(n - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I am new on C# i need help with set Decimal.Precision pls help.

I am trying to calculate n number of pi and write it.

Code can calculate but i dont know how can write n number of this calculation result.

Comment: Something like: `Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(pi, numberOfPlaces));`, I don't think I've ever seen someone set the `System.Decimal.Precision`, typically people Round or Floor/Ceiling the result.

Comment: If you are using `double`s in your calculation, don't use `decimal`, it just slows things down and adds no value

Comment: What's the point of the ones in `t=1*(Factorial(1))*(13591409+545140134*k)`

Comment: This has already been asked. Check this out. [How to calculate pi to N number of places in C# using loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677369/how-to-calculate-pi-to-n-number-of-places-in-c-sharp-using-loops)

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with π. It is just about number formats. But in fact, you did not ask a precise question.

Answer (score -1):

You can write out the substring of pi from 0 to n:

replace:
`Console.WriteLine(pi);`

with:
`Console.WriteLine(pi.ToString().Substring(0, (n > 1) ? n + 1 : n));`

the n + 1 logic increases the number of characters since the decimal "." does not count as a digit.  Notice to increase by 1 only if user specifies more than 1 digit (n > 1).