# How do I show all decimal points?

Tags: c#, .net, precision, pi

I'm currently trying to do:

```
double keyTimes = 789789347928325 * Math.Pi
Console.WriteLine(keyTimes);
```

And it gives me: `2.4811964133351E+15`

I need it to give me the full number of digits for a project, how can I achieve this?
I want something like: `2.4811964133351468979725207509245720957294570275973459709345787430` etc.

Comment: Hint: how many significant digits do you believe `double` is capable of holding, and what's your evidence for it? How many digits are you actually expecting to see? (How many digits do you believe would be in a "perfectly accurate" result from multiplying pi by 789789347928325?)

Comment: Pi can't be represented exactly in any number of decimal digits, bits, or any other base.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473136/can-c-sharp-store-more-precise-data-than-doubles

Comment: Also the `Math.PI` is a constant with 16 digits after a decimal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate pi to N number of places in C# using loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677369/how-to-calculate-pi-to-n-number-of-places-in-c-sharp-using-loops)

Answer (score 0):

`double` can hold up to 17 digits, so you should use the `decimal` which is the floating-point numeric type with the highest precision (28-29 digits). Since the `Math.PI` constant is a `double` too you would need to define your own:

```
var pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327m;
var keyTimes = 789789347928325 * pi;
// output 2481196413335099.0078141712097
```

To get better results you could try to find an external library. For example there is a [BigDecimal](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BigDecimal/) nuget, but it hasn't been updated for long.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain as many digits of PI as you want, e.g.

https://github.com/eneko/Pi/blob/master/one-million.txt (one million)

https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/contrib/pi/ (one billion)

Turn PI into `BigInteger`, do arithmetics, restore the decimal point:

```
using System.Numerics;

...

string piStr = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679";

BigInteger pi = BigInteger.Parse(piStr.Replace(".", ""));

BigInteger value = pi * 789789347928325;

string result = value.ToString().Insert(16, ".");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
2481196413335099.0078141712096700227201776435541531843170785955041765369811708253654976044892515801198900164883582675
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ogOWbR)